# MySQL - the cheapest order

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables:

```
Persons:
person_id
person_name

Orders:
person_id
cost
order_name
```

I need to make a ONE sql-query to get person name and it's cheapest order.
Want to write some like this: `SELECT person_name, order=(SELECT order_name FROM orders WHERE order.person_id = person.person_id ORDER BY order.cost ASC LIMIT 1) FROM person`
But it don't work.

Comment: Do a select on Persons, for the person_name.  Then JOIN the orders on person_id, and ORDER BY on orders.cost, ASC limit 1.  So you are almost there, just add a join.

Comment: Raises error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified. –

Answer (score 1):

I would use a correlated query. There are many ways to do it: as a subquery in the SELECT clause, or as a subquery in the WHERE clause.

In this case, I implemented the second option:

```
SELECT
    person_name,    
    order_name
FROM Persons 
    INNER JOIN Orders ON Persons.person_id = Orders.person_id
WHERE 
(
    cost = (
        SELECT MIN(cost)
        FROM Orders
        WHERE 
            (Orders.person_id = Persons.person_id)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `order=` and add `AS order_name`

Something like this:

```
SELECT p.person_name
     , ( SELECT o.order_name
           FROM orders o 
          WHERE o.person_id = p.person_id
          ORDER BY o.cost ASC
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS order_name
  FROM person p
 ORDER BY p.person_name
```

Comment: Raises error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: That would be an error in Microsoft SQL Server not MySQL. (The question is tagged as "mysql" not "sql-server")

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT person_name, order_id, order_name, MIN(cost) as cost
FROM persons
INNER JOIN orders
ON persons.person_id = orders.person_id
GROUP BY person.person_name, order_id, order_name;
```

You can do this just by joining your 2 tables and use `MIN`.